# XCTest examples, How to start with XCTest?

Tags: testing, xcode5, xctest

I think, that all what I found there about topic, are usefull information, but I need to know smaller steps.. How can I create test, How can I click and slide through some articles in app, how can I test long tap gesture,.. Please, some little examples which help beginners, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is called UI testing. XCTest is a framework for Unit Testing. What Apple provides for UI testing is another framework called [UI Automation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html). The Apple documentation is the best place to start looking for information.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode5 integrates with XCTest so it's very easy to get started.

The Apple documentation walks you through the whole process:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/developertools/conceptual/testing_with_xcode/testing_1_quick_start/testing_1_quick_start.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH2-SW1

It's not necessary to add all application files to the XCTest target. The test target only requires XCTest files.

If you receive linker errors when building the test target,
make sure *Symbols hidden by default* is set to **NO** within the application target.

This post outlines the process if it's unclear:
http://hackazach.net/code/2014/02/24/slim-xctest-targets/

Comment: Broken link, is there a new version